# Add fixed tax to prestashop order

Tags: php, smarty, prestashop

I'd like to add a fixed tax of 2 euros per order to an existing prestashop website. I already added it to every step the client makes, until the last step in which I'm not able to:

the file I want to modify is "modules/bankwire/views/templates/hook/payment_return.tpl" in which I have this line:

```
{l s='Amount' mod='bankwire'}: <span class="price"><strong>{$total_to_pay}</strong>
```

If I change the previous line to:

```
{l s='Amount' mod='bankwire'}: <span class="price"><strong>{$total_to_pay+2}</strong>
```

my final displayed price is rounded and no € symbol appears (for example if my total price is 54.50 €, when I add 2 euros to it, it becomes 56 instead of 56,50 €)

How can i manage it?

Thanks

Comment: Changing templates only won't do you any good. When a customer places an order, the tax won't be calculated into order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$total_to_pay` is a formatted price ("56,90 €" instead of "56.90") defined in bankwire module:

```php
public function hookPaymentReturn($params)
{
    if (!$this->active)
        return;

    $state = $params['objOrder']->getCurrentState();
    if (in_array($state, array(Configuration::get('PS_OS_BANKWIRE'), Configuration::get('PS_OS_OUTOFSTOCK'), Configuration::get('PS_OS_OUTOFSTOCK_UNPAID'))))
    {
        $this->smarty->assign(array(
            'total_to_pay' => Tools::displayPrice($params['total_to_pay'], $params['currencyObj'], false),
            'bankwireDetails' => Tools::nl2br($this->details),
            'bankwireAddress' => Tools::nl2br($this->address),
            'bankwireOwner' => $this->owner,
            'status' => 'ok',
            'id_order' => $params['objOrder']->id
        ));
        if (isset($params['objOrder']->reference) && !empty($params['objOrder']->reference))
            $this->smarty->assign('reference', $params['objOrder']->reference);
    }
    else
        $this->smarty->assign('status', 'failed');
    return $this->display(__FILE__, 'payment_return.tpl');
}
```

You can get the price like this using the order object:

```php
{displayPrice price=$objOrder->getOrdersTotalPaid()}
```